# msbuild continue buil solution on some project error in command line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, opencv3.0

Is any way to continue build solution from command line when error occured? Such as -i flag in make (g++) on linux.
Details: I try to build opencv 3.1.0 from VS 2010 command prompt, and have some error. In VS 2013 build and install is successful, in Linux I use -i flag for make and it allow me to continue build and install opencv without some examples. How I can do this in VS 2010 command prompt?
My command is for buils is:

```
msbuild /p:ContinueOnError=ErrorAndContinue /p:Configuration=Debug OpenCV.sln
```

PS. for create solution I use cmake.
PSS. I known that /p:ContinueOnError=ErrorAndContinue not working in this case.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's possible. Looks like the generated msbuild project file (as described in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe/) would need to set the RunEachTargetSeparately argument to false on the msbuild task. But I don't see any way to do so in the code: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/XMakeBuildEngine/Construction/Solution/SolutionProjectGenerator.cs